# Regex for extracting city from comma separated address

Tags: regex, street-address

I have an address like this:

```
123 Main St, Los Angeles, CA, 90210
```

I'd like to capture just the city:

```
Los Angeles
```

I've beeing trying tomsething like this:

```
(?:[^,]+),\s([^,]+)
```

But I don't understand how to return just the 2nd group. Using a flag like {2} seems to be including every up to the second group and not only the second group.

**UPDATE**

I'm using a Chrome extension that uses regex patterns, so using Javascript or another language is not possible in this case.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that maybe this expression might be of interest here,

```
(?<=,\s)([A-Z].*?)(?=[,\s]*[A-Z]{2}[,\s]*\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/V5qbGW/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/V5qbGW/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Your pattern worked based on the string I provided, but I ended up needing to account for full state names, so I tweaked your pattern and ended up with this: (?<=,\s)([A-Z].*?)(?=[,\s]*[A-Z]*[,\s](?:-\d{4})?)

Answer (score 2):

A general pattern you may try is:

```
^[^,]+,\s*([^,]+)
```

The city name would be available in the first (and only) capture group.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a regex for this? A split should be enough.

Example in JS:

```js
var str = "123 Main St, Los Angeles, CA, 90210";
var res = str.split(", ");
if(res.length>1)
{
  console.log(res[1]);
}
```

Example in Python:

```
s = "123 Main St, Los Angeles, CA, 90210";
r = s.split(", ")
if len(r) > 1:
  print(r[1])
```

Example in Java:

```
String s = "123 Main St, Los Angeles, CA, 90210";
String[] parts = s.split(", ");
if(parts.length > 1)
{
  System.out.print(parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Parsing csv's with regex is indeed a bit awkward